# How to retrieve JSON object's value if it's name keeps on changing

Tags: android, json

I am retrieving some info regarding some animals with help of mediawiki api
`http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=extracts&titles=Animal&format=json&exintro=1`
 but one of the object is pages which changes according to animal. How do I access page object(It contains the extract about animals)?

This is the JSON query result

```
    {  
   "batchcomplete":"",
   "warnings":{  },
   "query":{  
      "pages":{  
         "6598":{  
            "pageid":6598,
            "ns":0,
            "title":"Camel",
            "extract":"<p class=\"mw-empty-elt\">\n</p>\n<p>A <b>camel</b> is 
             an even-toed ungulate in the genus <i>Camelus</i> that bears 
             distinctive fatty deposits known as \"humps\" on its back. 
             Camels have long been domesticated and, as livestock, they 
             provide food (milk and meat) and textiles (fiber and felt from 
             hair). As working animals, camels\u2014which are uniquely suited 
             to their desert habitats\u2014are a vital means of transport for 
             passengers and cargo. There are three surviving species of 
             camel."
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: What variable is changing? @ "extract" - ?

Comment: First object in pages is changing, in this example it is "6598"

Comment: If you are using GSON with retrofit (mostly possible), you need to crate POJO for all cases, or you may use Shahin's answer  - extract data from JSON object one value by one...

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things you should consider:

1. Just Look for Response Status Code at the moment of Response, like:

   onResponse(){
   if (statusCode == 200){
      // --- Now Here Look for the Response Body Specific 
    }
   }
2. Use JsonObject as Model for Response Body, like:

```js
@Override
public void onResponse(Call < JsonObject > call, Response < JsonObject > response) {
  if (response.code() == 200) {
    if (!response.body().toString().isEmpty()) {
     // ----- Now Here You can Extract the JsonObject Field you are looking for
     // --- Example :
     
     JsonObject object = response.body();
     String target = object.get("field_name);
     
    } else {
      // Empty Response
    }
  } else {
    // Failure or whatever
  }
}
```

How are you getting this Response? Retrofit, Volley, OkHttp??

Each provide some kind of easy workaround for changing fields as well

Answer (score 1):

If I got that right - the "extract" value is changing in your JSON, if so just get it as a String value and set it to you TextView, with special tag - html, like this:

```
String  description;
TextView  tv_description;

tv_description = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.btn_desc);

tv_description.setText(Html.fromHtml(description));
```

Any other case, you need to create a POJO for all JSON varieties and use generic method.